# Can someone explain this probability reasoning?

Tags: probability

Question: Given you have 4 cards: a seven of hearts, a seven of diamonds, a six of clubs, and an 8 of spades. You take 3 at random and add the cards' values. Construct a table showing the probability distribution of the sum.

I was able to solve it fine but the solutions provide a very different method (it is also more concise so I would like to understand it)
So the sums are $20, 21$ or $22$ and I worked it out by taking the cases. Eg for $21$, it is only possible via $6,7$ and $8$ and there are 6 ways this can be arranged. Thus, $6(\frac{2}{4}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2})$ which is$\frac{1}{4}$. However, the solutions are as follows:
[image: solutions]
It just lists the set and then proceeds to $\frac{3}{4}$. How can 3 ever be in the numerator if there are only 2 "seven" cards?

Comment: Let's call a card in the set "good."  The probability that your first card will be "good" is $\frac 34$ because three of the four cards are "good."  If the first card is "good," the probability that the second card also is "good" is $\frac 23$ because two of the three cards remaining are "good."  If the first two draws are "good," the probability that the final card also will be "good" is $\frac 12$ because one of the two remaining cards is good.  So the probability that all three of the draws are "good" is $\frac 34 \times \frac 23 \times \frac 12$, which telescopes to $\frac 14$.

Comment: you said "a" card. So why is it $\frac{3}{4}$? Should it not be $\frac{1}{4}$ because you let one out of the 4 cards be "good"?

Comment: It would have been clearer if I'd written, "Let's call a card 'good' if it's one of the three cards in the set we're examining."  You want to know the probability, for any set, that all three of your draws will "good" with respect to that set.  Then you want to sum those probabilities across all sets with the same sum.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand this. (On my part). Could you Eli5?

Comment: Let's just consider the set $\{6$C, $7$D, $8$S$\}$.  What is the probability that the first card you draw will fall within that set?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what order you draw the cards in, so it seems like the most straightforward way to solve the problem is to focus on the leftover card.  Any of the four cards can be left over with equal probability.

So you'll get $20$ with probability $\frac 14$ (when the $8$ is left over).

You'll get $22$ with probability $\frac 14$ (when the $6$ is left over).

And you'll get $21$ with probability $\frac 12$ (when either of the $7$s is left over).